# Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 3 gRpc not generating service files

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I created a simple gRpc server application using the template in Visual Studio 2019. I then created a protobuf file for the server but I cannot get it to generate the corresponding service files.

The protobuf file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "RpcApi";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package API;

service Conferences {
    rpc GetAll (GetAllConferencesRequest) returns (GetAllConferencesResponse) {}
    rpc Add (AddConferenceRequest) returns (AddConferenceResponse) {}
}

message GetAllConferencesRequest {}

message GetAllConferencesResponse {
    repeated Conference Conferences = 1;
}

message AddConferenceRequest {
    Conference conferernce = 1;
}

message AddConferenceResponse {
    Conference conference = 1;
}

message Conference {
        int32 Id = 1;
        string Name = 2;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp Start = 3;
        string Location = 4;
        int32 AttendeeTotal = 5;
}

service Proposals {
    rpc GetAll (GetAllProposalsRequest) returns (GetAllProposalsResponse) {}
    rpc Add (AddProposalRequest) returns (AddProposalResponse) {}
    rpc Approve (ApproveRequest) returns (ApproveResponse) {}
}

message GetAllProposalsRequest {
    int32 ConferenceId = 1;
}

message GetAllProposalsResponse {
    repeated Proposal Proposals = 1;
}

message AddProposalRequest {
    Proposal Proposal = 1;
}

message AddProposalResponse {
    Proposal Proposal = 1;
}

message ApproveRequest {
    int32 Id = 1;
}

message ApproveResponse {
    Proposal Proposal = 1;
}
message Proposal {
    int32 Id = 1;
    int32 ConferenceId = 2;
    string Speaker = 3;
    string Title = 4;
     bool Approved = 5;
}
```

And the project file is correctly defined:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\rpcapi.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.23.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>



</Project>
```

Its supposed to generate server-side files whenever the proto file changes but it never generates those files. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It actually works. The files are generated in the obj directory and not the Services directory. If I do Show All Files, I can see them.